# Errors: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio

I am trying to query only 10 records and using LIMIT in query, but it is giving me the following error :

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect
>   syntax near 'LIMIT'.

Following is my query:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, EmailAddress 
    FROM MASTER_IMPORT
        WHERE EmailAddress LIKE "%gmail.com" LIMIT 10
```

Anything that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

SFMC uses T-SQL syntax, so you need to rewrite your query using the TOP expression instead of LIMIT.

```
SELECT TOP(10) SubscriberKey, EmailAddress 
FROM MASTER_IMPORT
WHERE EmailAddress LIKE "%gmail.com"
```

Also refer to official [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql) for more details on the TOP expression:

> Limits the rows returned in a query result set to a specified number
> of rows or percentage of rows.
>
> In a SELECT statement, always use an ORDER BY clause with the TOP
> clause. This is the only way to predictably indicate which rows are
> affected by TOP.

Comment: Thanks Eduard, however I would need the subsequent distinct email addresses that end with gmail.com in another Data Extension. How would that work ? Can I use 'NOT IN' in that case?

Comment: Also, when I use your code, it gives me the following error: 
An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Invalid format specification: '%gmail.com'.'. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes in your syntax '%gmail.com'

Comment: Yes Eduard, I got that working.. Any suggestion on my first comment? Can I use NOT IN for that?

Comment: @AshutoshArora Why not? Honestly, didn't quite understand what you needed in your first comment. I think you should try it, and if it doesn't work then post another question here with clear explanation and what you already did to solve the problem. Anyway, answering a non-related question in comments is not a good idea.

Comment: I tried posting that question but have no replies.. you can check it:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192782/updating-distinct-records-in-multiple-data-extension-from-a-master-de

Comment: @AshutoshArora please mark this answer as Accepted if it answered your question, so it may be useful for others